When I'm trying to access the firebase authentication I get the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
    const phoneInputField = document.querySelector("#phone");

    function getIp(callback) {
        fetch('https://ipinfo.io/json?token=af99e3dad456d9', { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }})
            .then((resp) => resp.json())
            .catch(() => {
                return { country: 'us' };
            })
            .then((resp) => callback(resp.country));
    }

    const phoneInput = window.intlTelInput(phoneInputField, {
        initialCountry: "auto",
        geoIpLookup: getIp,
        utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/utils.js",
    });

    document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", process, false);

    function process(event) {
       
        event.preventDefault();

        // Extract formatted phone number
        const phoneNumber = phoneInput.getNumber();

        // Log phone number for debugging purposes
        console.log("Formatted Phone Number:", phoneNumber);

        window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
        'size': 'normal',
        'callback': (response) => {
            // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
            sendOTP(phoneNumber);
        },
        'expired-callback': () => {
            // Response expired. Ask user to solve reCAPTCHA again.
            // ...
        }
        });

       
    }

    function sendOTP(phoneNumber) {
        var appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;

        firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
        .then((confirmationResult) => {
        // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
        // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
        window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
        // ...
        }).catch((error) => {
        // Error; SMS not sent
        // ...
        });
    }
</script>
   <script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.1/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.1/firebase-analytics.js";
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyCYcbJ2OeXyp70VvBvK7jiepIah04S4bic",
        authDomain: "fir-local-cf48d.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "fir-local-cf48d",
        storageBucket: "fir-local-cf48d.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "627101199334",
        appId: "1:627101199334:web:908a6f01f6bef042134427",
        measurementId: "G-CNLBT10S5Y"
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
    </script>

@endscript

When I'm trying to access the firebase authentication I'm getting the following error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined at HTMLFormElement.process (eval at safeAsyncFunction (livewire.js?id=e2b302e9:1249:21), \<anonymous\>:32:44)

What do I need to do to resolve this issue?

You are using Firebase functions before you have imported and initialized Firebase.
Move the initialization script to the top  and do not forget to import the Firebase authentication library, since you know... you're using it :
<script type="module">
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.1/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.1/firebase-analytics.js";
    import { getAuth, RecaptchaVerifier, signInWithPhoneNumber } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.1/firebase-auth.js";
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyCYcbJ2OeXyp70VvBvK7jiepIah04S4bic",
        authDomain: "fir-local-cf48d.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "fir-local-cf48d",
        storageBucket: "fir-local-cf48d.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "627101199334",
        appId: "1:627101199334:web:908a6f01f6bef042134427",
        measurementId: "G-CNLBT10S5Y"
    };
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
    window.firebaseAuth = getAuth(app);
    window.firebaseAuth = auth;
    window.RecaptchaVerifier = RecaptchaVerifier;
    window.signInWithPhoneNumber = signInWithPhoneNumber;
</script>

<script>
    // Your existing code
</script>


livewire.js?id=e2b302e9:1249 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
if i use this code at  top iam getting this error

@Srisailamkongalla Added the proper initializations.
